# convert normal string to latex string to use in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

So I know that if I want to use a LaTeX string in my plots I should instead of for example `"sin(x)"`, I should use `r"\sin(x)"`.

But if I have `a = "\sin(x)"` and I now want to use this `a` as my plot label, how can I convert it to `r"\sin(x)"`? When I do `type(r"\sin(x))"` is just says string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind that to have MathText activated the string must be in between Dollar signs (`$`).

In case your latex contains backslashes you need to either use a raw string from the beginning

```
a = r"$\tan(\nu\cdot x)$"
```

or escape the backslashes

```
a = "$\\tan(\\nu\\cdot x)$"
```

[image]

If you try something like in the other answer, you'd get unexpected results

```
a = "\tan(\nu\cdot x)"
b = r"$"+a+"$"
ax.plot(x, y, label=b)
```

results in
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `a = r"$\sin (x)$"`  Or alternatively convert variable a to b, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.gca() 
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  
y = [324,456,6,78,2,54]  # cramming numbers on my keyboard
a = "\sin(x)"
b = r"$"+a+"$"
ax.plot(x, y, label=b)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect, didn't think you could just put the `r` in front of it. I used `b = r a` but that of course does not work but this way it does.

Comment: The conversion you're doing here only works by pure coincidence. In the general case it will fail, try e.g. `a = "\tan(\nu\cdot x)"`.